# Loops using Numpy Vectorization

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I am trying to replicate the results that uses loops and numpy vectorization, article found here (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06).  The article does not include data or results from the run, but I was able to find the data online. I want to replicate the results for my own work but the output is not correct.

I have included a small portion of the original data frame from the article and the corresponding code:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'HomeTeam':['Burnley','Crystal Palace','Everton','Hull','Man City','Middlesbrough','Southampton',
'Arsenal','Bournemouth','Chelsea','Man United','Burnley','Leicester','Stoke'], 'AwayTeam':['Swansea','West Brom','Tottenham','Leicester','Sunderland','Stoke','Watford','Liverpool','Man United',
'West Ham','Southampton','Liverpool','Arsenal','Man City'], 'FTR': ['A','A','D','H','H','D','D','A','A','H','H','H','D','A']} 

leaguedf = pd.DataFrame(data) 

def soc_iter(TEAM,home,away,ftr):
    leaguedf['Draws'] = 'No_Game'
    leaguedf.loc[((home == TEAM) & (ftr == 'D')) | ((away == TEAM) & (ftr == 'D')), 'Draws'] = 'Draw'
    leaguedf.loc[((home == TEAM) & (ftr != 'D')) | ((away == TEAM) & (ftr != 'D')), 'Draws'] = 'No_Draw'

leaguedf['Draws']=soc_iter('Arsenal',leaguedf['HomeTeam'].values, leaguedf['AwayTeam'].values, leaguedf['FTR'].values)
leaguedf
```

When I run the code the output column 'Draws' only generates output of 'None', instead of 'Draw' or 'No_Draw'.

[image: results]

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything so Draws will be all None, you don't have to assign anything, the code inside the function is already creating the Draw column:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'HomeTeam':['Burnley','Crystal Palace','Everton','Hull','Man City','Middlesbrough','Southampton',
'Arsenal','Bournemouth','Chelsea','Man United','Burnley','Leicester','Stoke'], 'AwayTeam':['Swansea','West Brom','Tottenham','Leicester','Sunderland','Stoke','Watford','Liverpool','Man United',
'West Ham','Southampton','Liverpool','Arsenal','Man City'], 'FTR': ['A','A','D','H','H','D','D','A','A','H','H','H','D','A']} 

leaguedf = pd.DataFrame(data) 

def soc_iter(TEAM,home,away,ftr):
    leaguedf['Draws'] = 'No_Game'
    leaguedf.loc[((home == TEAM) & (ftr == 'D')) | ((away == TEAM) & (ftr == 'D')), 'Draws'] = 'Draw'
    leaguedf.loc[((home == TEAM) & (ftr != 'D')) | ((away == TEAM) & (ftr != 'D')), 'Draws'] = 'No_Draw'

soc_iter('Arsenal',leaguedf['HomeTeam'].values, leaguedf['AwayTeam'].values, leaguedf['FTR'].values)
leaguedf

           HomeTeam     AwayTeam FTR    Draws
0          Burnley      Swansea   A  No_Game
1   Crystal Palace    West Brom   A  No_Game
2          Everton    Tottenham   D  No_Game
3             Hull    Leicester   H  No_Game
4         Man City   Sunderland   H  No_Game
5    Middlesbrough        Stoke   D  No_Game
6      Southampton      Watford   D  No_Game
7          Arsenal    Liverpool   A  No_Draw
8      Bournemouth   Man United   A  No_Game
9          Chelsea     West Ham   H  No_Game
10      Man United  Southampton   H  No_Game
11         Burnley    Liverpool   H  No_Game
12       Leicester      Arsenal   D     Draw
13           Stoke     Man City   A  No_Game
```

Comment: Perfect.  This works.  The 'Draw' column was incorrectly referenced twice in the example.    Thanks for fixing!